# Rotates when I scramble Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, kineticjs

i have scrambled my puzzzle, now i need to have it rotated when i scrmable? can anyone help? Thanks :)

```
    fillPatternImage:imageObj,
                    x:-pieceWidth*i/2,
                    y:-pieceHeight*j/2,
                    stroke: "#000000",
                    strokeWidth: 4,
                    lineCap: "round",
                    draggable: true,
                x: i+pieceWidth/4 + (Math.random()*4)*((stage.getWidth()+pieceWidth)/12),
                y: j+pieceHeight/4 + (Math.random()*2)*((stage.getHeight()+pieceHeight)/12),
            });
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vFez6/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The general method to rotate a canvas drawing is:**

- save the context state: `context.save()`
- translate to the desired center of the object: `context.translate(centerX,centerY)`
- rotate by the desired radian angle: `context.rotate(Math.PI/4)`
- draw the object offset by 1/2 width & height: 'context.fillRect(-width/2,-height/2,50,30)'
- restore the context state to its unrotated state: 'context.restore()'

[image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7aqwjddt/

```
rotateRectangle(150,150,75,50,45*Math.PI/180);

function rotateRectangle(centerX,centerY,width,height,radianAngle){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(centerX,centerY);
    ctx.rotate(radianAngle);
    ctx.fillRect(-width/2,-height/2,width,height);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the trouble to ask you again, i tried your method but it doesnt change anything, so i added something in my code, and it gives me an error that now my whole picture doesnt came out, can you help me see agian? thanks :) sorry to trouble you once again, my editted fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/vFez6/26/                       i edited this part                                             var offsetX = pieceWidth * i *  Math.PI / 90;
var offsetY = pieceHeight * j *  Math.PI / 90;